# Define and execute partial functions of an interface

Tags: java

I am new to Java so i have some obvious (to some of you) questions about declaration, definition and execution of some functions.

Suppose you have declared two methods in an interface and you want to define the behavior of the first function in a (abstract?) class and the second function in another (abstract?) class.

Is there a way to define two methods in two separate classes? For example i could have a lot of methods in an interface but I want to implement just one of them because a specific object does not needs the others. How can I do that??

Java Code example :

```
interface DeclareFcnts {
    void foo1();
    void foo2();
}

abstract class Define_fcn1 implements DeclareFcnts {
    public void foo1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

abstract class Define_fcn2 implements DeclareFcnts {
    public void foo2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}

class Myclass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     // How can i create an object that reference to the first function only?
    }
 }
```

Comment: fat interfaces are evil. Can you change the interface?

Comment: alternatively (but not better!) you could instantiate required classes on the fly, as described e.g [here](http://tuhrig.de/implementing-interfaces-and-abstract-classes-on-the-fly/). This approach will save your time, because you won't need to manually write a lot of meaningless stubs. But still, it's a bad approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement an interface in a class, you must assume it will have all the interface methods declared. You must define what happens if any of these methods are invoked. Consider this:

```
DeclareFcnts instance = new Define_fcn1();
instance.foo2(); // what happens here?
```

What is your expected behavior on the second line? It could throw an exception, do nothing, (or return a value if the method wasn't `void`).

One option is to define the behavior in the concrete implementing class (because you cannot instantiate abstract classes), which is what you would like to avoid. Fortunatelly, in Java 8, there is another way - using [default methods](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/01/java-8-default-methods-explained-5-minutes/):

```
interface DeclareFcnts {
    default void foo1() { /* default implementation, e.g. throw or do nothing */ }
    default void foo2() { /* default implementation, e.g. throw or do nothing */ }
}

class Define_fcn1 implements DeclareFcnts {
    public void foo1() { /* do something */ }
}
```

In this case, `Define_fcn1` will inherit implementation of `foo2` from `DeclareFcnts` much like if it inherited from a super class. You can notice that the class no longer needs to be abstract.

---

That said, you should try to avoid such situations. They will make unit testing, refactoring, etc., more difficult. You may possibly split your interface into multiple interfaces. If you need both methods somewhere, you can pass the interfaces separately, or, if absolutely necessary, define another interface like this:

```
interface Foo1Iface { void foo1(); }
interface Foo2Iface { void foo2(); }
interface BothIface extends Foo1Iface, Foo2Iface {  }
```

I would avoid it if possible, though. You may get more suggestions if you add more details to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible, when you are implementing an interface you are obliged to @override those methods in that interface but you can leave it as blank assuming that you would not call it. Although:

This is your Generic interface, *it can be anything as long as you meet the requirements*.

[image: Our interface]

> Credits to Pinterest.

If you are going to design a house it does not make sense to add a wheel or anything unrelated to the house. Otherwise create a separate Interface for a Car or a Bus.

**An Example of Bad Design**

```
interface GenericInterface{

   public void defineDoor();

   public void defineWindow();

   public void defineWheel();

}
```

**The actual implementation**

```
class House implements GenericInterface{

   @Override
   public void defineDoor{
     // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void defineWindow{
      // do something
    }

    @Override
    public void defineWheel{
      // does not make sense to the House.
    }

}
```

Here is another class that implements the Generic Interface

```
class Car implements GenericInterface{

     @Override
     public void defineDoor{
       // do something
     }

     @Override
     public void defineWindow{
       // do something
     }

     @Override
     public void defineWheel{
       // do something.
     }

 }
```

Though our Car fits the above Interface but since when did the House contains a wheel?. The right way to do this is to create Separate Interface for Car and House.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this!
you must declare body for your method that declared in interface and then create instance of class
or you can use java 8 default declaration for your interface methods

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
public interface IX
{
void sayHello();
void sayBye();
default void showInfo()
{
    System.out.println("you call show Info method");
}
}
```